# I want to sort data into descending order in rails app and I used sqlite3 database. So is there any order_by available in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite3-ruby

/home/dell/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method` order_by' for User:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  order
irb(main):015>

I want to sort data into descending order in rails app and I used sqlite3 database. So is there any order_by available in rails.

Answer (score 1):

The method to return database records in a certain order is called [`order`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) in `ActiveRecord`.

It can be used like this: `User.order(name: :desc)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there any method  order_by in ruby on rails ?

Comment: I am not aware of an `order_by` method in Ruby or Ruby on Rails. There exists [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), but it sorts enumerables, not DB records. Why do you think there should be such a method, did you see it in a tutorial or article?